# SFTP - Connect via Terminal Osx

Tags: terminal, sftp

I'm trying to see if its possible to insert my password to below command.

```
sftp -o “Port 44444” myusername@mysite.com
```

Im looking to have a one line command to login into our sftp.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is not secure and therefore not possible with native OpenSSH tools. But you can use `sshpass`:

```
sshpass -p password sftp -o “Port 44444” myusername@mysite.com
```

or rather set up pubkey authentication:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
ssh-copy-id -o “Port 44444” myusername@mysite.com
```